# How to get date and time using moment for a given timezone offset

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

```
{
    "time": 1627375726.8367202,
    "tzoffset": -25200,
    "ok": 1
}
```

Using above JSON I need to get date, time and timezone. I have tried many ways but could not succeed. Is there a way to get date, time and timezone. I am using JavaScript.

Thanks,

Comment: Worth pointing out that moment is now effectively deprecated https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Check out there [Documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/parse-zone/)

A Little Example is here

```
moment.parseZone("2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00").utcOffset(); // -780 ("-13:00" in total minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use your specified unix time and offset to get the current date and time using the `moment.utcOffset` function. We have to divide your tzoffset by 60, since it is (presumably) in seconds whereas moment expects minutes.

It's usually not possible to get a unique timezone value, since your tzoffset is going to be shared by multiple zones, the best we can do is get a list of these:

```js
const input = {
    "time": 1627375726.8367202,
    "tzoffset": -25200,
    "ok": 1
};

console.log("UTC time:", moment.unix(input.time).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
console.log("Time in Timezone:", moment.unix(input.time).utcOffset(input.tzoffset / 60).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))
console.log("Time in Timezone (with offset):", moment.unix(input.time).utcOffset(input.tzoffset / 60).format())
console.log("Possible timezones:", getPossibleTimezones(input.time, input.tzoffset))

function getPossibleTimezones(time, tzoffset) {
    return moment.tz.names().filter(zone => moment.tz(moment.unix(time), zone).utcOffset() === input.tzoffset / 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

I'd also consider using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) since moment is now in maintenance.

We can use the FixedOffsetZone to get local time in that zone:

```js
const input = {
    "time": 1627375726.8367202,
    "tzoffset": -25200,
    "ok": 1
};

let { DateTime, FixedOffsetZone } = luxon;

let zone = new FixedOffsetZone(input.tzoffset / 60)

console.log("UTC time:", DateTime.fromSeconds(input.time, { zone: 'UTC' }).toISO())
console.log("Time in timezone:", DateTime.fromSeconds(input.time,  { zone: zone }).toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-bI2nHaBnCCpELzO7o0RB58ULEQuWW9HRXP/qyxg/u6WakLJb6wz0nVR9dy0bdKKGo0qOBa3s8v9FGv54Mbp3aA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```